# AWS Lambda NodeJS, can't make external connection

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

So, I'm trying to do a basic thing: Connect to an external REST-API from my AWS Lambda script.
This API hosts a list of holidays.

But, whenever I try to execute the code it just times out (max lambda execution time reached).

So I created this wrapper function, that is capable of handling 4 different ways of doing `GET` requests, but all of them perform the same.

```js
const request = require('request')
const https = require('https')
const axios = require('axios')
const superagent = require('superagent')

let test = (type = "") => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        debug("Fetching with: " + type)
        const d = new Date()
        if(type == "superagent"){
            superagent.get('https://holidayapi.pl/v1/holidays?country=DK&year=' + d.getFullYear())
            .query({ country: 'DK', year: '2019' })
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    reject(err)
                } else {
                    console.log(res)
                    resolve(res)
                }
            })
        } else if(type == "axios"){
            axios.get('https://holidayapi.pl/v1/holidays?country=DK&year=' + d.getFullYear())
            .then(response => {
                debug(response)
                resolve(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                reject(error)
            })
        } else if(type == "https"){
            const req = https.get("https://holidayapi.pl/v1/holidays?country=DK&year=" + d.getFullYear(), (resp) => {
                let data = ''

                // A chunk of data has been recieved.
                resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    data += chunk
                })

                // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
                resp.on('end', () => {
                    console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation)
                    resolve([])
                })
            })
            .on('error', (e) => {
                debug(e)
                reject(e.message)
            })
            req.end()
        } else if(type == "request"){
            request('https://holidayapi.pl/v1/holidays?country=DK&year=' + d.getFullYear(), { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
                debug(err)
                debug(res)
                debug(body)
                if (err) reject(err)
                else resolve(body.holidays)
            })
        } else {
            reject("Mangler type")
        }
    })
}

exports.connect_test = (event, context, callback) => {
    test(event.pathParameters.type)
    .then((rsp) => {
        callback(null, JSON.stringify(rsp, null, 2))
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        callback(null, JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
    })
}
```

The `debug` function is a map to console.log, that checks if the NODE_ENV is "dev".

Comment: Timeout could be a network issue, Is lambda lunched in VPC or without VPC ?

Comment: This definitely looks like a Network Issue. I would advice you to follow this [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/), and get back with your results.

Answer (score 2):

- I presume the default VPC has got internet connectivity, So if it's in the default it should just work (just increase the default timeout on the lambda to something reasonable).
- If its inside a VPC then you need to have NAT Gateway/NAT instance configured for that VPC to have internet connection or pair with another VPC that has an internet access(Inside the VPC lambda need to have appropriate role and subnet).
- This might help you [aws docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

Comment: It's inside a VPC (the default one). This might be the issue because it tracks with the changes I've made and when it stopped working. The VPC has IGW, DOPT, ACL and 3 subnets. Where would I find the setting that's blocking the traffic?

Comment: Your VPC doesn't have access to the internet. You'll have to enable it through the NAT Gateway attached to your VPC.

Comment: @Folkmann I have added a link to the answer above which might help you

Comment: Thanks for the help. Found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/reggi/dc5f2620b7b4f515e68e46255ac042a7) that explained the concept in a way that I understood. So, my lambda function has access to the API now :)