# Can't make an API call to an external service from AWS lambda (wo VPC)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, axios, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm using the `serverless` framework with an AWS lambda (node.js).

The lambda makes two API calls with `axios`- one `GET` and one `POST`. When running the function locally, everything works great, but when I deploy and run it in AWS the `POST` request just doesn't happen **but I don't get any error message in the logs**.

I saw some previous questions on this issue (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647811/aws-lambda-nodejs-cant-make-external-connection)), and they all mention that something needs to be defined in a function that runs in a VPC. This specific function doesn't have a VPC configured so I think this can't be the problem.

I've also enabled the cors in the `serverless.yml` (see below).

Any help would be appreciated.

#### serverless.yml

```
service: someservice
app: makingapps
org: orgname
frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 11111
  httpApi:
    cors: true

functions:
  myfunc:
    handler: myfunc.myfunc
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: get
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

#### myFunc.js

```
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports.myFunc = async (event) => {
    async function sendEmail(number) {
        console.log('[sendingEmail] function started' ) //Shows in the logs
        const message = `The number is ${number}`
        let options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://rapidprod-sendgrid-v1.p.rapidapi.com/mail/send',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'x-rapidapi-key': 'key-hash',
                'x-rapidapi-host': 'hostname.com'
            },
            data: {
                foo: [{'bar_key': 'bar_value'}],
                content: [{type: 'text/plain', value: message}]
            }
        };
        try {
            const emailResponse = await axios(options) 
            console.log(emailResponse.data); //Only shows in the log when run locally
        } catch(error) {
            console.error(error); //Doesn't show in the log
        }
    }


    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: null,
    };

    try {
      const numResponse = await axios.get('https://example.com');
      const number = numResponse.data
      console.log(number) //Shows on logs
      
      response.body = 'The current number is: ' + number;
      response.statusCode = 200;
      sendEmail(number);
      console.log('[main] after sendEmail function') //Shows in logs

    } catch (err) {
        response.body = err;
        response.statusCode = 'Error';
    } finally {
        console.log('Here is the response: ', response.body);
        return response;
    }
};
```

Comment: can you share the error message you are getting from the lambda logs?

Comment: No error... that's the thing

Comment: just try pritining the whole response `console.log(emailResponse);` and see if the necessary stuff is there. or not.

Comment: There's nothing there. No log. It's like the function doesn't reach this line.

Comment: Can you see anything logged in aws cloudwatch logs? Can you share whatever logs you find there? How do you invoke this lambda function?

Comment: @shanik1986 I'm curious if and how you resolved this problem, as I have been banging my head against the wall with the exact same scenario?

Answer (score 0):

`sendMail` is an `async` function. You have to `await` it.

Replace

```js
sendEmail(number);
```

```js
await sendEmail(number);
```

Comment: What accounts for the fact that the function runs fine locally?

Comment: @romeplow serverless-offline does not freeze your function after you return like what Lambda does.